# "Взлом" rot13 при помощи LSTM модели

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Реализовав LSTM модель для "взлома" rot13 я получил точность 100% на тренировочных данных,а на тестовых данных всего лишь 88%, у меня возникли сомнения по поводу правильности построенной мною модели.

```
latent_dim = 256
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.InputLayer((9, len(chars_in))))
model.add(layers.LSTM(latent_dim))
model.add(layers.RepeatVector(9))
model.add(layers.LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(len(chars_out))))
model.add(layers.Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
                                       metrics=['accuracy'])
Epochs = 120
Batch_size = 256
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=Batch_size, epochs=Epochs, 
validation_data=(x_val, y_val),callbacks=[checkpoint]
```

Хотелось бы узнать в чем моя ошибка,полный ноутбук по ссылке
[root13crackwithrnn](https://github.com/Korsaja/ML_and_NN/blob/master/rot13crackwithrnn.ipynb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несколько идей:

1. Похоже ваша модель переобучается, поэтому стоит попробовать воспользоваться одним из методов регуляризации, например добавить один или несколько слоев `Dropout()` и подобрать значение параметра. Начать можно с 0.2 или 0.3, посмотреть как реагирует `val_loss` и в соответствии с этим увеличивать или уменьшать значение
2. Лучший показатель точности предсказания на тестовых данных у вас `91.51%`, который на поздних эпохах несколько ухудшился. Поэтому стоит воспользоваться `callbacks` для сохранения лучшей модели и для ранней остановки (чтобы избежать бесполезных вычислений и ускорить время обучения модели):

   ```
   from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

   early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.0001,
                              patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')
   chkpt = ModelCheckpoint(model_filename, 
                           monitor='val_loss', 
                           verbose=1, 
                           save_best_only=True, 
                           mode='auto')
   callbacks = [early_stop, chkpt]

   hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                    batch_size=Batch_size, epochs=Epochs, 
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val), 
                    callbacks=callbacks)
   ```