# Сохранение лучшей модели

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

При обучении сети необходимо заранее указывать количество эпох обучения. При этом не обязательно, что сеть с каждой эпохой будет становиться лучше.

Можно ли организовать обучение сети таким образом, чтобы после каждой эпохи сравнивать получившуюся сеть с лучшей? Чтобы после того, как пройдет заданное количество эпох, была получена лучшая сеть за все время обучения, а не сеть после обучения на заданное количество эпох.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете [воспользоваться callbacks](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/860019/211923) для сохранения лучшей модели и для ранней остановки (чтобы избежать бесполезных вычислений и ускорить время обучения модели):

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.0001,
                           patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')
chkpt = ModelCheckpoint(model_filename, 
                        monitor='val_loss', 
                        verbose=1, 
                        save_best_only=True, 
                        mode='auto')
callbacks = [early_stop, chkpt]

hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                 batch_size=Batch_size, epochs=Epochs, 
                 validation_data=(x_val, y_val), 
                 callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно. А можно ли в качестве параметра `monitor` указывать не одну метрику, а несколько? Например, если я хочу отслеживать изменения не только по проверочной выборке, а, например, еще и по тестирующей?

Comment: @mtrfnv, а как вы собираетесь передавать модели тестовую выборку? ;)

Comment: Думал, мало ли есть способ) А так, видимо, действительно никак.